# Prove the Archimedean property from second-order Dedekind completeness OR prove the existence of the integers.

Tags: real-analysis, second-order-logic

**Context:**

I am taking an introductory real analysis class (because I need the credit), and the professor has provided me with their notes on the subject. In the notes, the professor defines the real numbers as the unique structure (up to isomorphism) characterized by the following axioms:

$$
\begin{align*}
[(1.1)] & \qquad \forall x\forall y\forall z((x+y)+z=x+(y+z))\\
[(1.2)] & \qquad \forall x\forall y \forall z ((x\cdot y)\cdot z=x\cdot (y\cdot z))\\
[(2.1)] & \qquad \forall x\forall y(x+y=y+x)\\
[(2.2)] & \qquad \forall x\forall y(x\cdot y=y\cdot x)\\
[(3)] & \qquad \forall x\forall y\forall z(x\cdot(y+z)=(x\cdot y)+(x\cdot z))\\
[(4)] & \qquad \forall x(0+x=x)\\
[(5)] & \qquad \forall x \exists y(x+y=0\land \forall z(x+z=0\iff y=z))\\
[(6)] & \qquad \forall x(1\cdot x=x)\\
[(6.1)] & \qquad 0\ne 1\\
[(7)] & \qquad \forall x((x\ne0)\implies\exists y (x\cdot y=1\land\forall z(x\cdot z=1\iff y=z)))\\
[(8)] & \qquad \forall x\forall y\forall z(x<y\implies x+z<y+z)\\
[(9)] & \qquad \forall x\forall y\forall z((x<y\land y<z)\implies x<z)\\
[(10)] & \qquad \forall x\forall y(x<y\lor y<x\lor x=y)\\
[(11)] & \qquad \forall x\forall y\forall z((x<y\land z>0)\implies x\cdot z<y\cdot z)\\
[(12)] & \qquad \forall P^1((\exists xP^1x\land\exists y\forall x(P^1x\implies x<y))\implies\exists y\forall x((Px\implies x\le y)\land\forall z(z<y\implies\exists x_1(Px_1\land x_1>z)))
\end{align*}
$$

Now according to my professor, "all of real analysis can be derived from these axioms" (this isn't true, of course, on account of the concepts from topology which are included in most real analysis courses, but I understand what they were trying to say.)

However, I'm skeptical about this claim. Specifically, I don't see any way to prove the Archimedean property from these axioms.

**Prove the Archimedean property from second-order Dedekind completeness:**

When I brought this up to the professor, they said that the Archimedean property was provided in the form of a theorem which states:

> For every real number $x$, there exists an integer such that $n<x<n+1$.

However, in the proof of this theorem they assumed that the integers are exactly the elements of $\Bbb R$ obtained by *finitely many* additions and subtractions of $1$ - a property which I pointed out was not proven in the notes, and cannot be proven by first-order means. Based on a heuristic argument I would guess that for any limit ordinal $\lambda\in\omega_1$, there should be a model whose "integers" are order-isomorphic to $\lambda^*+\lambda$. The professor agreed that this at least *seems* reasonable, citing that restricting the integers as desired *without* using second-order logic or adding a new predicate to the language would require the infinite disjunction:

$$x=0\lor x=0+1\lor x=0+(-1)\lor x=0+1+1\lor\cdots$$

I then asked if there is a second-order proof of the desired property somewhere else, to which my professor responded that they "don't work with second order logic," and suggested that I look at Dedekind's *Essays on the Theory of Numbers*.

This completely failed to answer my question.

It seems to me that my professor, whose primary area of research is set theory, takes for granted the standard set-theoretic implementation of the naturals, integers, rationals, and reals (specifically using Dedekind cuts). Their reasoning seems to fall along the lines of "ZFC with the particular encoding of numbers that I am used to proves it, so we needn't worry about the details." But this isn't what I was promised. I was told that all of real analysis could be derived from the axioms *listed above*, not that all of real analysis can be represented in ZFC!

I know that Dedekind completeness of the real numbers implies the Archimedean property *given* the set-theoretic definition of the naturals as the smallest infinite well-order, but any set theory capable of talking about a "smallest" *anything* is already *much* stronger than the second-order theory of the reals. If I say "I can run from New York to Los Angeles in a day," I can't prove it by taking a commercial flight, so if we're going to make the claim that "these axioms uniquely characterize the real numbers," then we ought to prove it using *these axioms*.

With that in mind, I would like to know how, if at all, the Archimedeam property can be derived from these axioms.

(Once more: *without* assuming set theory)

---

**OR prove the existence of the integers:**

The proof of the Archimedean property in the notes essentially consists of "the integers are the subset of $\Bbb R$ containing all elements obtained by finitely many additions and subtractions of $1$," "the integers are unbounded" and "for every real number $x$, there exists an integer $n$ such that $n<x<n+1$." In order to prove this, we first need to define the integers. To this end, let

$$\sigma_\Bbb Z:=\forall x(P^1x\iff (x=0\lor \exists y (P^1y\land (y+1=x\lor y=x+1))))$$

Then $\exists !P^1\sigma_\Bbb Z$ is the formula asserting the existence and uniqueness of the set of integers (uniqueness is required so that the extension obtained by adding the predicate symbol $Z(x)\equiv`\text{$x$ is an integer'}$ is conservative). This is where I get lost. I don't really know anything about second-order logic, so I have no idea how to prove $\exists!P^1\sigma_\Bbb Z$.

Once this is done, however, the proof that the integers are unbounded is straightforward. Following that, we may state the Archimedean property as

$$\exists!P^1(\sigma_\Bbb Z\land\forall x\exists y(P^1y\land y<x<y+1))$$

Once we have proven the existence of the integers, the original proof that "for every real number $x$, there is an integer such that $n<x<n+1$" should be sufficient for this purpose.

---

**Aside:** Is this a set theory/model theory question? I mean, I'm trying to *avoid* thinking in terms of set theory, but at the same time the potential for unintended models is the whole reason for the problem.

Comment: Set theory is unavoidable once second-order logic enters the picture (as long as you're using the standard semantics as opposed to the *Henkin semantics*). But we can define the set of integers in the following way: $z$ is an integer iff $$\forall P^1(0\in P\wedge \forall x(x\in P\rightarrow x-1\in P\wedge x+1\in P)\implies z\in P).$$ This is the "smallest inductive set" approach to the integers (more-or-less). And at a glance, the axioms your professor gave you (again, assuming the standard semantics for SOL) do pin down $\mathbb{R}$ up to isomorphism. (cont'd)

Comment: Note that this latter claim can be phrased, and proved rigorously, inside the (first-order!) theory ZFC. This is the sense in which ZFC is (usually) "in the background" when  we do second-order logic; prima facie second-order claims about $\mathbb{R}$ or similar are understood as first-order claims in set theory. Of course we lose theory-completeness (not to mention categoricity) when we make this shift, but it (arguably) gives us a firm footing for making second-order claims.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I'm well aware that all of the desired properties can be proven in ZFC. I am not disputing this at all. I want to know if the existence of the integers can be proven in theory *presented*, not some other theory.

Comment: @NoahSchweber As I said if I say "I can run from New York to Los Angeles," I can't prove it by taking plane. If I say "this theory proves everything about the reals," I can't prove it by using a different theory.

Comment: You've misunderstood my point. I'm saying that that's *not a complete question*. A theory doesn't exist in a vacuum; it exists within some broader logic context (what are the inference rules?). In the case of SOL, that broader context already assumes some set theory, so to a certain extent what you're asking for doesn't parse. That said, I've given a second-order definition of the integers in my first comment. Any reasonable system (= sound but not complete unfortunately) you use for second-order logic will let you prove the relevant version of Archimedeanness from the given axioms.

Comment: Specifically, any reasonable proof system for second-order logic will be able to prove the expression $$\forall x\exists y[x<y\wedge \forall P^1(0\in P\wedge \forall z(z\in P\rightarrow z-1\in P\wedge z+1\in P)\rightarrow y\in P)]$$ from the axioms you've written, which reads as "Every $x$ is less than some $y$ which is an integer."

Comment: What is a "reasonable proof system" for second-order logic?

Comment: E.g. a proof system which is sound-and-complete with respect to Henkin semantics (that will still be sound, but not complete, with respect to the standard semantics). More generally, any sound "computably presented" proof system.